# Geography type in Ms Sql Server 2012 being stored as binary?

Tags: sql-server, geography

I trying to insert some coordinates into my database yet every time I do so it just says `<Binary data>` in the value.

I tried

```
geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326)
geography::STPointFromText('POINT(55.9523783996701 -3.2051030639559)', 4326)
geography::Point(51.4618933852762, -0.926690306514502, 4326)
```

Is it normal for it just to say `<Binary data>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, internally UDTs (User Defined Types), which is how `geography` is implemented, get stored as binary, however, they are recognized by the database engine as being more than that.

SQL Server automatically deserializes the binary back into a .NET object when you access it, and also serializes the .NET object to binary for storage.

So, when you call methods on UDT instances, whether in a variable or a column, they respond as you would expect:

```
declare @var geography = 
       geography::Point(51.4618933852762, -0.926690306514502, 4326);

select @var.ToString()
```

Comment: Anyways to get it to show that when you look at in the designer. Kinda sucks that I can visually see it when looking at it.